# ASP.NET Core MVC - Access Cookies data in non-Controller class

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to write a function that get token from cookie that is non-controller , I need *Helper* to get cookie.
I use ASP.NET Core MVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can put the token in the cookie like this:

```
CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions();
                    options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(6);
                    Response.Cookies.Append("Token", Result.Value.Token, options);
```

get the parameters by this code in your auth:

```
ActionExecutingContext filterContext
```

after that if the token was in the cookie like below you can get that

```
var Token = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"];
```